# Serving dynamic downloads in Node + Express

Tags: node.js, express, coffeescript

I am trying to respond to a POST from a web page by sending a file generated by Node.js on-the-fly. I would rather avoid the naive way of saving the file to disk and then calling res.download.

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467620/dynamically-creating-a-file-with-node-js-and-make-it-available-for-download), I have tried the following coffee:

```
app.post "/post", (req, res, next) ->
  mydata = "I want to write this to a file"
  res.setHeader 'Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename="myFile.txt"'
  res.setHeader 'Content-type', 'text/plain'
  res.write mydata
  res.end()
```

It does not work, though. I just get the same page where my form was, as if it refreshed. I have redirecting to a GET with res.redirect and app.get, but it doesn't work either.

**EDIT**

I have tried the above code together with a very simple express server. It works if I submit a form data with method="post". However, what I want to do is to send data through jQuery's post(). This is my JS:

```
$('form').find(':submit').click();    
if ($('form')[0].checkValidity()) {
    $.post('/post', js);
}
```

Here, js is simply a javascript object. I have tried removing the click() and even the checkValidity() parts; that helps with the reloading of the page, but I still cannot download myFile.txt.

Can anyone shed some light?

Thanks

Comment: Do you [prevent default event](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) upon submitting the form?

Comment: @mutil I was sending the data via jQuery's post(), but at the same time I was force-clicking on a submit <input>  to do HTML5 validation. That should be it, thanks.

Comment: Well, that took care of the page reloading, but I am still not able to get the file

Comment: If you post the relevant HTML and JS of the form, maybe I can be of more help

Comment: Your data will be available in the response of your $.post request. You're making an ajax request, this will not reload the page with the data you're sending back, you'd need to send the form in the regular way for that and do a redirect

Comment: Ah, of course! I mixed up some concepts in here. Thanks!